# In cs50x labs volume.c, Why in do while reading samples we don't shift to end of header before reading samples?

Tags: c, cs50

**CS50x Labs 4: volume.c**

The problem is to change volume of a `".wav"` file `(variable: input; type: FILE)` into another `".wav"` file `(variable: output; type:FILE)`.

We read the header of size 44 bytes using this code (as also given in the solution)

```
uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
fread(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, input);
fwrite(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, output);
```

This is fine, reading 44 bytes from input then storing it into header and finally writing it to output file.

Further, for reading each sample the code is

```
int16_t buffer;
while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
{
    buffer = buffer * factor; //change volume
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
}
```

Now, A `".wav"` file begins as

- 44 bytes header
- sequence of samples (each 2 bytes) representing audio which needs to be multiplied for volume changes.

In the 2nd part of the code, we use `while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))`. It reads 2 bytes from input at a time and stores it in buffer. Which we later multiply (for volume change) and store it in output.

But, Isn't it also reading header (1st 44 bytes) 2 bytes at a time and multiplying it with factor as we haven't mentioned anywhere to start reading from 45th byte as that's where samples start from.

This is the solution given by CS50x team, it works properly. But, it still feels wrong.

- 1st to 44th byte: should remain as it is.
- 45th to ... byte: read 2 at a time and multiply by factor.

This doesn't seems to be happening here?

Comment: The `fread` call moves the file pointer by the number of bytes it successfully reads. Thus, after reading the 44 byte header, the file pointer will be on the 45th byte, already.

Comment: We have no idea, what the code you are talking about, is doing. Assuming that you don't close/open the file again and don't rewind or set the file pointer to start position after reading the header, it will stay exactly there until you read the next data. In your case until you read the series of 2 byte values till you reach the end of the file.

Comment: Yes. When you read the first 44 bytes for the header, the pointer for *input is already at the 45th byte. So if you don't call rewind(input) the pointer will still be at the 45th byte. I believe you can also for the second part rewind the input pointer, offset the pointer by the header size then read u_int16 until eof as well, but that's a round about way of doing it.